# Passing Element ID (in Parameter) to Function (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, function, parameters

I am trying to create a tap-holding selection for mobile phones (small screen).

I have a table with one check-box for each row. Their ID's are created dynamically (from PHP).

I want the user to check/uncheck those checkboxes if he/she tap-holds one of the table rows.

I found this jQuery script on how to perform the tap-holding event.

```
$("tr").on("taphold",function(){
   //....
});
```

I can use `this` to get an element but I trigger the event on tr and not for checkbox. If those IDs of the checkbox are made dynamically, how can I pass the element ID as a parameter?

In javascript, I can do it like this (for clicking)...

```
function selectItem(elementID)
{
   // Do something...
}
```

And I called that function in html...

```
<tr onclick="selectItem('record1')">
```

I should use jQuery because JavaScript don't have the tap-hold event.

How to do something like this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").on("taphold", function(){
    //get me an input with type checkbox inside this element
    var checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]', this);
    //check it
    checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    //you can also get its ID
    alert(checkbox.attr('id'));
});
```

Also, have a look at this part of the documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

My answer assumes that you have this HTML structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>My item 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>My item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>My item 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you add more info about the HTML I can help you better.